# Changing directory in a pthread

Tags: pthreads, chdir

My question is :
How can i change the current directory in a pthread without changing the current directory in other pthreads, I found a solution which is using openat() function, but i didn't found any example explaining how it works.
Using chdir() changes the current directory in all pthreads in the process.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `openat()` method is an *alternative* to changing the current working directory.  Instead of calling:

```
chdir("/new/working/directory");
open("some/relative/path", flags);
```

you instead use:

```
dirfd = open("/new/working/directory", O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
openat(dirfd, "some/relative/path", flags);
```

This is the POSIX-standard way to avoid changing the process-wide current working directory in a thread, but still work with relative paths.

There is a also a Linux-specific way to give the current thread its own current working directory, separate from the rest of the process - `unshare(CLONE_FS);` - but this is not portable.

Comment: Thank you very much ,i'm working on linux ,the unshare function is perfect to do this.